# how to make wcf service listen for soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 (in code)

Tags: wcf

I naively made a basicbinding for 1.1 and a webhttbinding for 1.2 and added them as endpoints to the same host

```
    var basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
    basicBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = clientCredType;
    s_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), basicBinding, "");

    var httpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = clientCredType;
    var httpsEndpoint = s_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), httpBinding, "");
```

wcf objects saying

```
   If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. 
The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.
```

EDIT: maybe I need to slightly rephrase. Can the same endpoint (say mything.org/service) support 1.1 and 1.2. Ie by simply looking at the payload the wcf service will determine how to read it

Comment: You need to specify different addresses for the two enpoints - for example "SOAP11" and "SOAP12".  You can't have two different endpoints at the same address.  Example:  `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), httpBinding, "SOAP12");` and `AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), basicBinding, "SOAP11");`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `AddServiceEndpoint` via your `ServiceHost` object, you are specifying `""` for the address argument twice. This is being interpreted as a relative URI - relative to the base address of the `ServiceHost`. So both endpoints end up with the same address in this situation.

This itself is not a problem, but it becomes one when they are of different bindings which is what you have (`BasicHttpBinding` and `WebHttpBinding`).

From [Specifying an Endpoint Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN:

> If you have multiple endpoints, each of which is configured with a
>   different binding, their addresses must be unique. Endpoints that use
>   the same binding but different contracts can use the same address.

If you are interested into the reason why a single `ListenUri` in WCF cannot support multiple bindings. The [Multiple Endpoints at a Single ListenUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN states:

> ... endpoints at the same ListenUri must have the same binding,
>   because they are sharing a single channel stack that listens for
>   messages at that physical address on the machine.

To solve this problem, you need to specify a non-empty string for at least one of the endpoints. This will do the trick:

```
s_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), httpBinding, "http");
```

**Related to your situation, but not to the problem:**

[`WebHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) is a binding for Web services that are exposed via HTTP requests instead of SOAP-based messaging. I believe you are looking for [`WSHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports SOAP 1.2.